# Math and PHP to find and print permutation sets

Tags: php, math

I have a quiz of 6 questions that must be answered either yes (y) or no (n). So the set of answers might be

> yynynn

For another quiz of 6 questions the answers might be

> nnnynn

For another,

> ynynyn

I need a script to find and print the unique permutations of answer sets.

Comment: Please, post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Why? This is just binary. You know the list. There are 2^6 = 64 permutations.

Comment: Just count from 0 to 63. Convert the values to binary, then convert the digits `1 => y` and `0 => n`.

Comment: Or use 6 nested `for ($var in ['n', 'y'])` loops, and concatenate the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<64;$i++)echo(strtr(substr("000000".decbin($i),-6),"01","ny")."\n");
```

The idea is to treat each combination as a binary representation of a number. Each of the 6 places (digits) can be either n=0 or y=1. So you count from 000000<sub>2</sub> (0 in decimal) to 111111<sub>2</sub> (63 in decimal). You convert each number to binary representation using `decbin`. You pad to a length of 6, which I did by prefixing some zeros and then taking the last 6 characters. Then you turn `0` to `n` and `1` to `y`, e.g. using `strtr`. Done.

Comment: This one liner really is a good answer.